# How to restore the Window menu to a perspective?

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally turned off the Window menu from my Debug perspective; does anyone know how I can turn it back on?

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using?Juno, Kepler ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the perspective where you want to re-enable **Window** Menu. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>. Then type **Customize Perspective**. In the **Menu** category or in the **Command** category choose **Customize Perspective** option.

Then the customize perspective dialog will open. Go to **Menu Visibility** tab and re-enable **Window** menu.